# Line height changing in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm working on two different apps. Most of the app is already done, I just have a few things to change.

I'm working on a page that has to be the exact same on the two apps ("Help page"). Therefore, I've copied and past my 3 files : help.h, help.m, help.xib

In this page, I have a UIWebview that displays a html local file. I've copied and past it too.

The problem is that in the two apps, the line height of the content of my UIWebView is different. Even though I have the exact same help.h, help.m, help.xib, help.html

It's general to the app because I have the same problem on an other view.

What property is supposed to control this ? Maybe a UIScrollView property as I know a lot of work has been done on UIScrollViews here.

As you can see below, the space between the last black box and the separator is different:

[image: App 1]
[image: App 2]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking EVERYWHERE, I've finally found where the problem came from : the typography. The "line height" was different.